# ORM for Stored procedure only: preferred tool

Tags: .net, orm, ado.net

Usually I use Entity Framowrk as my ORM tool.
And I really like 'Function Import' feature and code generators.

But once I read in on very thick and very serious book that its not good idea to use EF for calling SP only.

Only a littly thing the author forgot: **What tool is the best for such DB calling strategy?**

Comment: Do you experience some problems when using EF with stored procedures?  Something does not work?  Is it slow?  Why do you want to change your ORM?

Comment: it' OK I like it very much. But ... I am not alone in my department :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out BLToolkit, very low learning curve compared to EF

Check out also this Blt extension -> [bltoolkit-storedprocedures2csharp-t4/](http://code.google.com/p/bltoolkit-storedprocedures2csharp-t4/)
Uses T4 templates to generate functions for your stored procedures

Normal Bltoolkit

```
using(var db = new DbManager())
{
  return db
    .SetSpCommand(
      "Person_SaveWithRelations",
      db.Parameter("@Name", name),
      db.Parameter("@Email", email),
      db.Parameter("@Birth", birth),
      db.Parameter("@ExternalID", exId),
    )
    .ExecuteObject<Person>();
}
```

With the extension

```
using (var db = new DataManager())
{
  return db
    .Person
    .SaveWithRelations(
      name,
      email,
      birth,
      exId
    )
    .ExecuteObject<Person>();
}
```

(Disclaimer:not used extension myself since I don't have a lot of SP's)

Answer (score 2):

If you have invested time in learning EF and it works for you stick with it. Alternatively for most projects micro ORMs like Dapper, Massive and PetaPoco will suffice. Dapper, for example, was developed to be used @ StackExchange I believe - it is now open source.

Answer (score 0):

I think Data Access block from the [Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/) is the best choice. I have used it in few projects to query external databases with only store procedures. The latest version is quite straightforward in configuration and convenient to use. It also doesn't overload you with extra functionality and provides only what you need. 
Use it if you want something simple and quick in configuration and usage, this is my advice.

Answer (score 0):

try to use BLToolkit - it is open source and allows to map object to stored procedure parameters and to map stored procedures output to objects without any problem

[bltoolkit home](http://bltoolkit.net/)
[bltoolkit sources](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit)